# Discord java - SelectMenu is stuck on the option you selected

Tags: java, discord

```
public class TicketSelectMenu extends ListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
        if (event.getAuthor().isBot()) return;
        if (event.getMessage().toString().startsWith("-bug-select-menu")) return;
        String[] args = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split(" ");
        EmbedBuilder eb = new EmbedBuilder();
        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("-bug-select-menu")) {
            TextChannel ticketchannel = event.getGuild().getTextChannelById("1013242063971696721");
            event.getMessage().delete().queue();
            eb.setColor(Color.decode(Config.colorEmbedAll));
            eb.setTitle("Ticket - Bug");
            eb.setDescription("You can report a bug on this channel");
            eb.setFooter("Ticket - Bug");
            SelectMenu ticketinteraction = SelectMenu.create("ticket-bug")
                    .setPlaceholder("Click to expand the category... \uD83E\uDD16")
                    .addOption("Bug - Discord", "bug-start-ticket-discord", "\uD83D\uDCBB Click to open the application menu.")
                    .addOption("Bug - Server", "bug-start-ticket-server", "\uD83D\uDCBB Click to open the application menu.")
                    .addOption("Bug - Web", "bug-start-ticket-web", "\uD83D\uDCBB Click to open the application menu.").build();
            assert ticketchannel != null;
            ticketchannel.sendMessageEmbeds(eb.build()).setActionRow(ticketinteraction).queue();
        }
    }
}
```

Once you select a given option from SelectMenu, you cannot interact with it a second time - SelectMenu is stuck on the option you selected. The only way to select the same option a second time is to select a different option from the SelectMenu. Is there any possibility to reset the SelectMenu after making a selection so that it returns to the Placeholder?

JDA version - 5.0.0-alpha.10

Comment: You can restart your discord client to clear it

Comment: Yeah i know, but i'm talking about automatic reset after selected option. Is there any possibility to do it?

Comment: You can explicitly set the select menu again in an edit request, there is an open issue to make the UX better https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/discussions/5896